# Cannot interact with different layout objects

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, xamarin, android-edittext

In Xamarin, I have the following `Layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:padding="5dip">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/List"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="Find..."
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The `mapWithOverlay` is the `Layout` for a Google Map.

The `inputSearch` is an `EditText` that is used to search for map locations.

The `List` is a `ListView` that displays the items searched for in the `inputSearch` `EditText`

Currently, the Google Map that is displayed in the `mapWithOverlay` cannot be interacted with. No clicks are registered.

My question is this: How can I rearrange, or change my layout such that the `EditText` can be interacted with as well as the `mapWithOverlay`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't interact because listview is present on the top of the relative layout layer.You've to pass  `android:layout_marginTop="50dp" android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"` in your fragment(here below listview 50dp height is remain to show any view).

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:padding="5dip">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/mapWithOverlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"                
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/List"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:hint="Find..."
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please give me some example layout code derived from my layout in my post? I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: This works, however I see a large black area under my EditText. How can I remove this black area?

Comment: I think the black area is for listview. Reduce listview size and pass this size into framelayout marginTop.

Comment: Currently my ListView does not have a specific size as it is loaded dynamically. How should I code this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the height and width in java class using

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Get the reference of List and inputSearch.

Set the margin of list and input search according to your visibility.